# How to customize dropdown menu tab/tabset in rmarkdown, _site.yml, YAML

Tags: html, r, yaml, r-markdown

I have a sample code [in here](https://rstudio4edu.github.io/rstudio4edu-book/rmd-dress.html). To add some extra text I used `-text:`. I would like to make

```
- text: Will be provided
- text: upon email request.
```

format identical to `href:` and also italic. Many thanks in advance.

```
 menu:
  - text: "CVs"
  - text: "English CV"
    href: ./SK_Cover.pdf
  - text: "Italian CV"
    href: ./SK_Cover_it.pdf  
  - text: "------------" 
  - text: "Docs"
  - text: "Certificates"  
    href: ./images/Certificates.pdf  
  - text: '---------'
  - text: "Reference Letters" 
  - text: Will be provided
  - text: upon email request.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This will require a little bit of webdev skills. The best I could do was make everything in the navbar(menu bar) have italics, you just need to adjust your selection of CSS paths. You may need to do some further coding. Mine is just an attempt.

You can use inline css directly in your `index.rmd` if you'd like. I am hoping that this would include any navbar text including what you are requesting. But

````
```{css results="asis"}
<style>
html body div.container-fluid.main-container div.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top     div.container {
   font-style:italic;}
</style>
```
````

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. But I would like to make it italic `-text: Will be provided upon email request.`

Comment: From what I could tell, you can't Markdown specifically at that line, you will have to use CSS to target that line.